# AWS Elastic Beanstalk application folder on EC2 instance after deployed?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

## My context

I'm having errors in my deployment using AWS EB with my Flask application.

Now I'm inside the EC2 instance via `eb ssh` and need to explore the deployed source code of the application.

## My problem

Where is the deployed application folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source code is zipped and placed in the following directory:

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle
```

There is no file extension but it is in the zip file format:

```
[ec2-user@ip ~]$ file /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/deploy/appsource/source_bundle: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
```

Answer (score 0):

Find for a specific/unique filename in source code folder, we will find the location of our application folder which, in AWS EB, to be

```
/opt/python/current
/opt/python/bundle/2/app
```

p.s.

Search for YOUR_FILE.py

```
find / -name YOUR_FILE.py -print
```