# Access Files in My Resources Folder Elastic Beanstalk/ Spring Boot

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, filesystems, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed a Spring Boot application that needs to read files stores in the resources folder in a jar and also save files while doing some processing. Trying to access my resources folder on Elastic beanstalk (t2.small) gives:

Input path does not exist: file:/var/app/current/resources/data/url_list1.csv

I tried to access the file using "System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resources/data/url_list1.csv"

I have tried how it is done on localhost on my system:

System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/resources/data/url_list1.csv"

It is not working. I know a lot of people have experience in this.

I found a solution:

I saw this answer on where the jar files is unzipped on aws elastic beanstalk and I had to look for the file.

[AWS Elastic Beanstalk application folder on EC2 instance after deployed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38968741/aws-elastic-beanstalk-application-folder-on-ec2-instance-after-deployed/38986418#38986418)

find / -name YOUR_FILE.py -print
 Found the file here in /tmp folder

/tmp/eb_extracted_jar/BOOT-INF/classes/data/url_list1.csv

So that is where elastic beanstalk kept the files unzipped from the jar I’m not an expert in Linux.   So I had to hardcode it into the application. I don’t know if there is any other way to access it dynamically from a Spring boot application with relative to the class path. I was feeding the file path to JavaSparkContext.textFile which requires a string to the file path. Meanwhile the classpath for the application defaults to    /var/app/current/ when the application is running.

Answer (score 0):

All resourses are moved to target folder. You can get the path by calling `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/data/url_list1.csv");`

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring Boot Elastic Beanstalk and OpenPDF (itext open source version), here is how i got it to work

```
Resource input = new ClassPathResource("assets/Logo.png");
Image freightOneLogo=Image.getInstance(input.getURI().toString());
```

I tried several other ways but could not get it to work.
The file is located in "resources/assets/Logo.png"